# in tax_query this Is the code correct? I need to access beginner video posts for different subject

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'videolesson',
        'ordeby'            => 'rand',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'    => 8,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'level',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'beginner',
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'vidsubjects',
                        'operator' => 'EXISTS'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
    );
    $getting = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Note that your orderby random is going to be expensive ( unexpectedly expensive getting more expensive/slow as the number of posts rises ), you also misspelt `orderby`. I would also question why a random ordering would be descending, random has no order

Comment: I need get posts type = videos, your taxonomies in case tax = beginner for differect tax = subjects.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'videolesson',
            'ordeby'            => 'rand',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page'    => 8,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'level',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'beginner',
                        'compare' => 'IN',

                    ),
                    array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'subjects',
                       'operator' => 'EXISTS'
                    )

                ),
        );
        $getting = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: i don't know if that works similarly or not but what i did here is take an array one level out

Comment: I need get posts type = videos, your taxonomies in case tax = beginner for differect tax = subjects.  @Howdy_McGee